# How to access a PHP file of Magento 1.9 extension from some external API

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm making a new plugin (extension) in Magento 1.9. The API department wants to access some particular PHP file from API externally.

Is there some way to do this?

Is it possible that some API can access the Model or controller file of magento extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "access" a model or a controller.
If you mean, "access" as in "use that class", then the answer is NO.
If you mean, "access" as in "make a call and get the response", the answer is yes.
You can make a controller that can be accessed via `http` calls.  [Here is a random tutorial](https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html) on how to create a simple controller.

But this will allow you to create a controller that can be accessed by anyone that knows the URL.
If you want to extend the magento API. But this gets a little more complicated and it involves a lot of code. [Here is another random example](http://www.ipragmatech.com/customize-magento-rest-api/) on how to do this:

Comment: Actually the API department wants to access some file from my  magento extension and then will send some data in it . I have to use that particular data in some cases .

Comment: that's the point of an api, right? Someone make a call sending some data and gets back the result based on that data.